# Symfony 2:image paths in javascript file with assetic

Tags: javascript, image, symfony, path, assets

I'm trying to make a path to an image from a js file in my symfony2 project using asset like this:

```
   var arr = $('<img src="{{ asset("assets/images/linkArrow.png")}}">').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    ...
    });
```

but I'm having the following error

```
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - mywebsite.com/bundles/web/app_dev.php/project/1/assets
   /images/linkArrow.png"
```

my image is under the web/assets file.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML / JavaScript source look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use twig syntax in your JavaScript file. If you can put your script in your template file it would work then. another clean way would be define a assets base path variable for your javascript. For example, to solve your problem you can add following code in your layout template:

```
<script>
    var assetsBaseDir = "{{ asset('assets/') }}"
</script>
```

**NB: Make sure you define this script before loading the javascript file, if you are referencing the variable directly in your js file**

then you can use it in all your JavaScript files Like:

```
var arr = $('<img src="' + assetsBaseDir + 'images/linkArrow.png'+ '">').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    ...
});
```

Happy coding!